# The computer hangs but does not swich off

Tags: shutdown

I use ubuntu 16.04 on a lenovo legion. When i try to swich it off, the computer hangs and I have to keep the power botton pressed.

**EDIT**
The exact laptop model is Y520-15IKBN

output of `uname -a` :

```
Linux mattia-Y520-15IKBN 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `sudo lshw`:

```
mattia-y520-15ikbn        
    description: Notebook
    product: 80WK (LENOVO_MT_80WK_BU_idea_FM_)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Y520-15IKBN
    serial: PF0X5Z8T
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80WK_BU_idea_FM_ uuid=EDDD3B2B-C6E6-E711-8A95-54E1ADFDF15C
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: VIUU4
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: SDK0K17763 WIN
       serial: PF0X5Z8T
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: 4KCN40WW
          date: 10/17/2017
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2858MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti retpoline intel_pt rsb_ctxsw spec_ctrl tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 24
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 0
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: RMSA3260MH78HAF-2666
             vendor: Ramaxel
             physical id: 1
             serial: 1244E02E
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 05
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:a3000000-a3ffffff ioport:90000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:321 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:322 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:a4390000-a439ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: HP Link-5 micro dongle
                   vendor: HP
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 3.21
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: EasyCamera
                   vendor: Bison
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 53.18
                   serial: 151027
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: b
                   bus info: usb@1:b
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:a43b0000-a43b0fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:323 memory:a43b1000-a43b1fff
        *-storage
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:319 memory:a43a0000-a43a7fff memory:a43b3000-a43b30ff ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5088(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:a4300000-a437ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:a4200000-a42fffff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: O2 Micro, Inc.
                vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:a4201000-a4201fff memory:a4200000-a42007ff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:a4100000-a41fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Intel Corporation
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 99
                serial: cc:2f:71:e2:be:5e
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-43-generic firmware=29.610311.0 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:324 memory:a4100000-a4101fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:a4000000-a40fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: enp4s0
                version: 10
                serial: 54:e1:ad:fd:f1:5c
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:320 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4004000-a4004fff memory:a4000000-a4003fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-H PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a43ac000-a43affff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:325 memory:a43a8000-a43abfff memory:a4380000-a438ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a43b2000-a43b20ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000LM035-1RK1
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: LCM2
             serial: WDEG5PGM
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=71d06c57-c367-4333-a303-4ba35003c4b5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: b4d2-7b1e
                size: 255MiB
                capacity: 259MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=SYSTEM_DRV name=EFI system partition
           *-volume:1
                description: reserved partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                serial: 739aa166-e274-4905-b560-c3323e98f10d
                capacity: 15MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: f6f56815-c2e1-ed4a-bb75-a894d21393ed
                size: 782GiB
                capacity: 782GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-03-30 05:40:18 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: aa8f22cb-a416-1444-bf1a-9ab31e90c02e
                size: 24GiB
                capacity: 24GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-03-30 05:55:21 filesystem=ntfs label=LENOVO modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 021789c5-28d4-0245-98d4-39bf6e1c4ed1
                size: 994MiB
                capacity: 999MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-03-30 05:40:26 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRE_DRV modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:5
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 426ca01d-4af1-4883-a940-ee1aebe7ba7c
                size: 108GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2018-05-27 16:09:09 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-05-31 15:45:10 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2018-05-31 13:45:19 state=mounted
           *-volume:6
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 1
                serial: 42e3c348-8e63-4bc9-aeb4-40356a67e8fa
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
  *-battery
       description: Zinc Air Battery
       product: CRB Battery 0
       vendor: -Virtual Battery 0-
       physical id: 1
       version: 08/08/2010
       serial: Battery 0
       slot: Fake
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include more detail? What's the exact laptop model? Which graphics adapter(s) does it use and which driver(s) did you install for it/them? What's the output of `uname -a` and `sudo lshw`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster How do I find *Which graphics adapter(s) does it use and which driver(s) did you install for it/them*?

Comment: Don't worry, that info is already included in the `lshw` output. I have two ideas that you can try: 1) upgrade the kernel through Canonical's HWE packages (`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` and reboot) and 2) [install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver](/q/61396/175814).

Comment: Which is the best option according to you  @DavidFoerster?

Comment: The best option is to try either and, if that fails, then the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs it, I answer my own question with the details of my experience.

Following @DavidFoerseter comment, I have installed the new kernel, but it made things worse: the computer freezed even before I could do anything, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

On the other hand, installing the most recent Nvidia driver proved to be the correct step; following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/61433/743263) I wrote in a terminal the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nvidia-396
sudo reboot
```

Notice that the correct driver's name is `nvidia-396` and not `nvidia-driver-396` as claimed in the cited answer. This can be seen using the command

```
apt-cache search nvidia
```

that checks for available Nvidia driver on the repository.