# Will I experience problem after the upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

When I frist installed Ubuntu on my laptop, I had [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042191/743263) problem (the computer hangs and never shuts down) which I solved installing the NVIDIA drivers. This happened both with 16.04LTS and 18.04LTS, in fact with the latter I could do nothing since the computer frezed even before I could do something (and that's why I ended up installing the 16.04LTS). So I was wondering:

If I upgrade to 1804LTS will I experience the same problems again?

Comment: When upgrading you should always hope for no problems but be prepared for many including the possibility of having to restore backups if things go terribly wrong.

Comment: Impossible to answer the question definitively - we don't have your hardware to test out upgrades upon. I think @WinEunuuchs2Unix advice is the best you will get.